# Add a new level to a factor and substitute existing one

Tags: r

I'm having a big trouble on dealing with levels names of a data frame.

I have a big data frame in which one of the colums is a factor with a LOT of levels.

The problem is that some of this data are duplicated and the next step in my analysis do not accept duplicated data. So I need to change the name of the duplicated level so I can move on to my next step.

Let me give you a little example:

Say we have this simple data frame with one colum:

```
> df
col_foo
1   bar1
2   bar2
3   bar3
4   bar2
5   bar4
6   bar5
7   bar3
```

If we look at the column, we see that it is a factor with 5 distinct levels.

```
>df$col_foo
[1] bar1 bar2 bar3 bar2 bar4 bar5 bar3
Levels: bar1 bar2 bar3 bar4 bar5
```

Ok, the problem comes now. See that levels `bar2` and `bar3` are **duplicated**. What I want to know is how can I add a level name, something like `bar2_X` and substitute only the duplicated one for this. So the dataframe should become this:

```
> df
col_foo
1   bar1
2   bar2
3   bar3
4   bar2_X
5   bar4
6   bar5
7   bar3_X
```

Is that possible ? I cannot change the class of the column, it should still be a factor, so solutions that need to change it will not solve my problem unless it is possible to coerce to factor again.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all the entries to be unique then a factor does not gain you much over just using a character variable.

Probably the simplest way to do what you want is to coerce to a character vector, use the `duplicated` function to find the duplicates and paste something onto the end of them, then if you want use `factor` to recoerce it back to a factor.  Possibly something like:

```
df$col_foo <- factor( ifelse( duplicated(df$col_fo), 
                    paste(df$col_foo, '_x', sep=''), as.character(df$col_foo)))
```

Comment: +1 for the reminder of _why_ we use factors in the first place.

Comment: This would be  the perfect way to do what I want, but somehow this is changing the names of the non-duplicated levels also, so I'm getting:

    > df
    col_foo
    1       1
    2       2
    3       3
    4  bar2_x
    5       4
    6       5
    7  bar3_x

Comment: wrap the else part in `as.character`, I fixed this in the example.

Comment: @Lianzinho: Are there any instances of a factor level occuring 3 or more times? (Check with `table(df$col_foo)`.) If so, the values with the `_X` suffix won't be unique.

Answer (score 10):

Call `make.names` with `unique = TRUE` on your column.

```
df$col_foo <- factor(make.names(df$col_foo, unique = TRUE))
```

Comment: This is a VERY useful tip! Thanks!

But for my case, I would like to really add a suffix to differentiate, the ".1" is very generic because I'm dealing with some codes which already have them in the name, things like: ENST00000381184.1

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the levels of the factor variable:

```
levels(df$col_foo) <- c(levels(df$col_foo),"bar2_X","bar3_X")
```

and then change the repeated levels to one of the new levels you added.